# Azure Cloud Service and App Service metrics

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics, azure-redis-cache

The metric logs of Redis Cache can be logged to a storage account using Diagnostics. Similarly where are the metric logs for cloud service and app service stored?